# Non-standard ways to post json to ASP.NET WebAPI2

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am modeling a RESTful service based on WebAPI2, but met some non-standard ways to post data (json) according to PRD (Product　Requirement Document) and a bit confused of how to implement these ones:

1. There should be an **input : type = file** button and user upload ***.json** file from PC. Service should post it.
2. There should be methods\ways to upload ***.json** by passing the file-path to browser's addres bar. `.../api/data-gather?path="C:/..../*.json"`
   Also this one should work too:`.../api/data-gather?name=Abba&Id=13dsx` (pass raw-string and it should be converted into json)
3. Another problem is that json files **doesn't contains** the same data-model:`user.json` contains fields like `name="Abba", id="12dsx"` and `company.json` may contain `location="Milton"`. 
   **How should I organize process of storing all this objects in DB** if I don't know what type of data will be posted? I think of using **Dynamic list** and checking for data inside this dynamic each type.
4. And last way to post is via Androis\iOS applications. I should give to another developer-team just API string like **api\upload** and OnClick method phone creates *json and my service should accept it.

Could you just provide simple instructions of way\algorithm for each case?

Comment: `.../api/data-gather?path="C:/..../*.json"` this does not make sense, if the path represents a file on the client, then this simply isn't possible.

Comment: What if the path sent as a string parameter, can't we get access to client PC by this string? Something like host address...path to file?

Comment: There is no way to access to the client file system from the server using HTTP. Also, many of those *requirements* are truly client-side problems, I do not understand why you are trying to address them server-side and not client-side.

Comment: *How should I organize process of storing all this objects in DB*... There are books written about how to do that. It's way too big of a topic for SO. Also, SO is not a code- or tutorial-writing service. You might have to do some research of your own.